# How to grab location information in the XML using linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My xml looks like:

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
  <Response> 
    <name>90210</name> 
    <Status> 
      <code>200</code> 
      <request>geocode</request> 
    </Status> 
    <Placemark id="p1"> 
      <address>Beverly Hills, CA 90210, USA</address> 
      <AddressDetails Accuracy="5" 
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
        <Country>
          <CountryNameCode>US</CountryNameCode>
          <CountryName>USA</CountryName>
          <AdministrativeArea>
            <AdministrativeAreaName>CA</AdministrativeAreaName>
            <SubAdministrativeArea>
              <SubAdministrativeAreaName>Los 
                Angeles</SubAdministrativeAreaName>
              <Locality>
                <LocalityName>Beverly Hills</LocalityName>
                <PostalCode>
                  <PostalCodeNumber>90210</PostalCodeNumber>
                </PostalCode>
              </Locality>
            </SubAdministrativeArea>
          </AdministrativeArea></Country>
          </AddressDetails> 
          <ExtendedData> 
            <LatLonBox north="34.1377559" south="34.0642330" 
              east="-118.3896720" west="-118.4467160" /> 
          </ExtendedData> 
          <Point>
            <coordinates>-118.4104684,34.1030032,0</coordinates>
          </Point> 
    </Placemark> 
  </Response>
</kml>
```

I need the information in extended data i.e. values for north/south, east/west.

Comment: All right. How far did you get when you tried to implement it yourself?

Comment: Very funny. Come back after you've tried.

Comment: I always get stuck when starting a new linq snippet, its not second nature to me yet that's for sure. thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also drill down though all of the nodes.  But this is probably the simplest way to get the `LatLonBox` element.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var ns = "{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0}";
var extendedData = xml.Descendants(ns + "LatLonBox").First();

var locationBox = new
{
    North = float.Parse(extendedData.Attribute("north").Value),
    South = float.Parse(extendedData.Attribute("south").Value),
    East = float.Parse(extendedData.Attribute("east").Value),
    West = float.Parse(extendedData.Attribute("west").Value),
};
```

... to drill down the elements you can do this ...

```
var extendedData = xml.Element(ns + "Response")
                      .Element(ns + "Placemark")
                      .Element(ns + "ExtendedData")
                      .Element(ns + "LatLonBox");
```

Comment: The xml namespaces can be rather messy.  Using the `ns +` like I did above dramatically simplifies the mess.

Comment: thanks allot, so you are also using an anonymous class there?

Comment: for `locationBox` yes.  you could replace that with a class definition or split it into 4 variables if you want.  If you were trying to process a set of elements you could also put that into your LINQ statement.

Comment: I should note that there are plenty of places in this code can could throw null reference exceptions.  But if you are using this against a known schema you can probably ignore the possible Null values.  Each of the chained `.Element(...)` methods and the `.Value` after the `.Attribute(...)` could each throw a null ref.